# retrieving column value based on string name of the column that is another column

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a pandas dataframe like:

```py
a b  colname
1 10 a
2 30 b
3 40 a
```

What is the most elegant value without using `iterrows` to create another column that will get a value of a corresponding column based on the name of the column from `colname`?

Comment: Deprecated `lookup` function. See [the document](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-lookup) for an implementation.

Answer (score 1):

`numpy` with `get_indexer` select with position

```
df['new'] = df.to_numpy()[np.arange(df.shape[0]),df.columns.get_indexer(df.colname)]
df
Out[214]: 
   a   b colname new
0  1  10       a   1
1  2  30       b  30
2  3  40       a   3
```

Notice we used to have `lookup` but this function not available anymore